# Why does the Rust compiler complain that I use a moved value when I've replaced it with a new value?

Tags: rust

I am working on two singly linked lists, named `longer` and `shorter`. The length of the `longer` one is guaranteed to be no less than the `shorter` one.

I pair the lists element-wise and do something to each pair. If the `longer` list has more unpaired elements, process the rest of them:

```rust
struct List {
    next: Option<Box<List>>,
}

fn drain_lists(mut shorter: Option<Box<List>>, mut longer: Option<Box<List>>) {
    // Pair the elements in the two lists.
    while let (Some(node1), Some(node2)) = (shorter, longer) {
        // Actual work elided.
        shorter = node1.next;
        longer = node2.next;
    }
    // Process the rest in the longer list.
    while let Some(node) = longer {
        // Actual work elided.
        longer = node.next;
    }
}
```

However, the compiler complains on the second while loop that

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value
  --> src/lib.rs:13:20
   |
5  | fn drain_lists(mut shorter: Option<Box<List>>, mut longer: Option<Box<List>>) {
   |                                                ---------- move occurs because `longer` has type `std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<List>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
6  |     // Pair the elements in the two lists.
7  |     while let (Some(node1), Some(node2)) = (shorter, longer) {
   |                                                      ------ value moved here
...
13 |     while let Some(node) = longer {
   |                    ^^^^ value used here after move
```

However, I *do* set a new value for `shorter` and `longer` at the end of the loop, so that I will never use a moved value of them.

How should I cater to the compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the problem is caused by the tuple temporary in the first loop. Creating a tuple moves its components into the new tuple, and that happens even when the subsequent pattern matching fails.

First, let me write a simpler version of your code. This compiles fine:

```
struct Foo(i32);
fn main() {
    let mut longer = Foo(0);
    while let Foo(x) = longer {
        longer = Foo(x + 1);
    }
    println!("{:?}", longer.0);
}
```

But if I add a temporary to the  `while let` then I'll trigger a compiler error similar to yours:

```
fn fwd<T>(t: T) -> T { t }
struct Foo(i32);
fn main() {
    let mut longer = Foo(0);
    while let Foo(x) = fwd(longer) {
        longer = Foo(x + 1);
    }
    println!("{:?}", longer.0);
    //        Error: ^ borrow of moved value: `longer`
}
```

The solution is to add a local variable with the value to be destructured, instead of relying on a temporary. In your code:

```
struct List {
    next: Option<Box<List>>
}

fn drain_lists(shorter: Option<Box<List>>,
               longer: Option<Box<List>>) {
    // Pair the elements in the two lists.
    let mut twolists = (shorter, longer);
    while let (Some(node1), Some(node2)) = twolists {
        // Actual work elided.
        twolists = (node1.next, node2.next);
    }
    // Process the rest in the longer list.
    let (_, mut longer) = twolists;
    while let Some(node) = longer {
        // Actual work elided.
        longer = node.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: The pertinent issue is that creating a tuple moves its components into the tuple. In the last iteration of the first loop, when pattern matching fails, the tuple is still first constructed, resulting in a move. This is unrelated to non-lexical lifetimes, though.

Answer (score 1):

Other than getting rid of the tuple (shown by others), you can capture a mutable reference to the nodes:

```rust
    while let (&mut Some(ref mut node1), &mut Some(ref mut node2)) = (&mut shorter, &mut longer) {
        shorter = node1.next.take();
        longer = node2.next.take();
    }
```

The use of `take()` enables this to work: `shorter = node1.next` would complain of moving a field out of a reference, which is not allowed (it would leave the `node` in an undefined state). But `take`ing it is ok because it leaves `None` in the `next` field.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the destructuring on line 7 moves the value even when the block afterwards is not evaluated. (Edit: as @Sven Marnach pointed out in the comments, a temporary tuple gets created here which causes the move) 
I've uglyfied your code to prove that point :)

```
struct List {
    next: Option<Box<List>>
}

fn drain_lists(mut shorter: Option<Box<List>>,
               mut longer: Option<Box<List>>) {
    // Pair the elements in the two lists.
    match(shorter, longer) {
        (Some(node1), Some(node2)) => {
            shorter = node1.next;
            longer = node2.next;
        },
        (_, _) => return  // without this you get the error
    }
    // Process the rest in the longer list.
    while let Some(node) = longer {
        // Actual work elided.
        longer = node.next;
    }
}
```

When I added the return for the default case, the code compiled.

Comment: Creating the tuple is what moves the value. Your code fixes a different problem.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll update the answer. As I understand it, this fixes the use after move, not the move itself, it that what you're referring to as the different problem?

Comment: @thbusch: I don't read minds, but quite likely. Specifically, the code now has different semantics => the longer-only loop is never executed...

Comment: The problem with the original code is that the tuple is still created in the iteration the pattern matching fails. The solution in this answer only works for a match statement, not for a `while let` loop, so the code does something entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to avoid the tuple and consequently the move of longer into the tuple.

```
fn actual_work(node1: &Box<List>, node2: &Box<List>) {
    // Actual work elided
}

fn drain_lists(mut shorter: Option<Box<List>>, mut longer: Option<Box<List>>) {
    while let Some(node1) = shorter {

        if let Some(node2) = longer.as_ref() {
            actual_work(&node1, node2);
        }

        shorter = node1.next;
        longer = longer.map_or(None, move |l| {
            l.next
        });
    }
    // Process the rest in the longer list.

    while let Some(node) = longer {
        // Actual work elided.
        longer = node.next;
    }

}
```

Comment: The elided actual work presumably needs access to `node2` as well, so you need to extract it in some way inside the loop. You could use an `if let` statement for that, but it makes this version of the code more cumbersome than rodrigo's solution.